# Limitar tipo de documento a subir en wagtail

Tags: python, django, cms

He intentado limitar el tipo de archivos a subir desde el administrador en wagtail. Creé una clase que me permita subir varios documentos de la siguiente forma:

```
    page = ParentalKey(BlogDetailPage, related_name="attachments")
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtaildocs.Document',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="+",
        verbose_name="Documento",
    )

panels = [
        DocumentChooserPanel('document')
    ]
```

Y para seleccionar el documento por medio del CSM uso esta opción:

```
        
        MultiFieldPanel([
            InlinePanel("attachments", label="Documentos importantes.")
        ], heading="Subir documentos."),
       ]
```

Sin embargo, en este apartado quisiera que se pudiera limitar la opción para que solo se puedan subir archivos de tipo .pdf, ¿hay alguna forma de poder crear esta restricción?

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente la forma correcta de hacerlo sea creando un validador que certifique que el documento está en formato PDF.

Esto se podría hacer de forma fácil validando que la extensión se .pdf con algún tipo de manipulación de cadenas, sin embargo, bastaría con que alguién cambié la extesión de un archivo para poder subirlo sin ser un PDF. Aún así está opción no es descartable si lo que quieres es velocidad y tus usuarios son confiables.

Sin embargo si necesitas más seguridad podrías a hacer el validador con la librería python-magic, que es capaz de detectar los tipos de archivo por sus cabeceras, metadatos, etc.

Para la primera opción [esta respuesta es muy útil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648421/only-accept-a-certain-file-type-in-filefield-server-side). Para la segunda podés ver el repositorio de [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic)

Creo que para casi cualquier caso la segunda opción es mucho mejor.